# Android - Detecting Garbage Collection

Tags: android, garbage-collection

Is there a way to detect when an activity has been garbage collected in Android? I just want to test different scenarios when garbage collection is initiated and try to do work arounds.

```
Intent it = new Intent(ActivityOne.this, ActivityTwo.class);
startActivity(it);
ActivityOne.this.finish();
Log.d(TAG, "Ending");

try {
    ActivityOne.this.finalize();
    Log.d(TAG, "possible garbage collected");
} catch (Throwable throwable) {
   throwable.printStackTrace();
   Log.d(TAG, "finalize not successful");
}
```

Comment: What work arounds are you wanting to do? The fact that it is being garbage collected means there is no reference left to the Activity (object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to detect when an activity has been garbage collected in Android?

Not really.  But it is good to test scenarios ex. finishing an activity to return a result when the first activity is no longer there.  I had a bug once where `onCreate` would (re)run to re-create the activity I assumed was already there and that caused an issue.

What you *can* do to test these cases is:

1. Enable Developer Options (you have probably already done this)
2. Under "Apps" category, enable "Do not keep activities"
3. Do your testing/debugging